# React Hook - setData with pure function to use prevData but with a deep comparison inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```
export function CurrentUserProvider({ children }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
  
  return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider
      value={{
        data,
        setData,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and I am doing the following to update the data:

```
const currentUser = useContext(CurrentUserContext);

currentUser.setData((prevData) => {
   ...prevData,
   totalFollowers: prevData.totalFollowers + 1
});
```

Now I need to avoid unnecessary state updates. But I also need to be able to access the setData pure function.

My idea was to deep compare the new data object, updating my CurrentUserProvider:

```
export function CurrentUserProvider({ children }) {
  const [data, _setData] = useState(undefined);

  const setData = (newData) => {
     if(!lodash.isEqual(newData, data)) {
        setData(newData);
     }
  }
  
  return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider
      value={{
        data,
        setData,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

But... with this, I am not able to access prevData. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the equality check inside the `setState` callback, and if they are equal, return the previous state. According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

> If your update function returns the exact same value as the current
> state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely.

```
export function CurrentUserProvider({ children }) {
  const [data, _setData] = useState(undefined);

  const setData = useCallback(newData => {
    _setData(prevData => lodash.isEqual(newData, prevData)
      ? prevData
      : { ...prevData, ...newData }
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <CurrentUserContext.Provider
      value={{
        data,
        setData,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CurrentUserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: there's a typo there `{ setData(` should be `{ _setData(`; and also `useCallback` might not be needed. Try without and see what happens.

Comment: Fixed the typo. Thanks. I want the updated `setData` to stay the same even if the component re-renders, so I would go with `useCallback`. However, you can try removing it, and see if it causes re-renders in your case.